# REST Assured returns response of "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '****/api/Document/getBrowserData'"

Tags: httpresponse, rest-assured

I have implemented my REST Assured code like below

```
String tempUrl = "***/api/Document/getBrowserData";
        Response  rjson  = given()
                .param("dsId",1108)
                .param("isNew", false)
                .param("oToken","eed0361d314888a3f153534844869d9f")
                .param("projId",837)
                .param("tId",-1)
                .param("type",2195)
                .param("userId",104)
                .post(tempUrl)
                .then()
                .extract()
                .response();
        System.out.println(rjson.asString());
```

and when I perform some action on the response:

```
System.out.println(rjson.asString()); // "Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches
the request URI '
System.out.println(rjson.getHeaders()); // header value 
System.out.println(rjson.getStatusCode());  // 404
```

But when I do the same thing with PostMan I am able to get a valid response.

Comment: How your raw requests look like? Did you try tools like WireShark?

Comment: @  RocketRaccoon no i have not tried with WireShark but when i posted the request passing all of the parameters in the tempUrl it worked might be some schema issue in the json format i guess

Comment: Did you try given().log().all()? How does your request looks like? May be you have prepopulated basePath, baseUri somewhere before in code.

Comment: @  RocketRaccoon thanks i haven't done that yet let me do that and revert you back